# How to get environment inside a view?

Tags: express, pug

I'm using Express with Jade. How can I get the environment from within my view?

In JS, I can get it with `app.get('env')`. How do I get it from Jade?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put it in as a variable when you render your view, in jade it would look like this

```
p Environment: #{appEnv}
```

And in the route that controls that view you should do something like this

```
res.render("viewName", { 
        appEnv: app.get('env')
    });
```